# why use Session post a data contain a empty tuple,the status_code always 400

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post

```
#-*- coding:utf8 -*-
import requests

if __name__=='__main__':
    session = requests.session()
    params={}
    a=()
    params.update({'id':a})
    httpresult = session.get('http://www.baidu.com/',data=params)
    print httpresult.status_code
    httpresult = session.get('http://www.baidu.com/')
    print httpresult.status_code
```

Expected Result
200
200

Actual Result
200
400

if i change the a to a str,the result is right. why??

Comment: Why should it accept an empty tuple? If it accepts an empty string then why not just use that? 400 is Bad Request.

Comment: I did not get 400 in response,even when i ran this code on linux-python3.x

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an empty tuple as the variable `a` and then trying to use that empty tuple as a query parameter, which will return an error.

Having said that; I just ran your code (in python3 with minor adjustments) and it returns the following

```
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> session = requests.session()
>>> params={}
>>> a=()
>>> params.update({'id':a})
>>> httpresult = session.get('http://www.baidu.com/',data=params)
>>> print(httpresult.status_code)
200
>>> httpresult = session.get('http://www.baidu.com/')
>>> print(httpresult.status_code)
200
```

So no 400 error.

Besides that you are using wrong query parameters for baidu, there is no id parameter.

It also possible that baidu is spotting your requests as a bot and blocking your requests for  limited time.

Comment: you try on linux, is ok?

Comment: Yes  I use Ubuntu 18.04.1 x86_64 and it works fine with no 400 response code